# Screenshots of a local HTML5 page/DIV

Tags: html, canvas, screenshot

I have a html page which has animations which will play over time, i  need to take screenshots of the webpage at some intervals (say after every second) and save the images to the disk, so i can use them for further processing,

Its alright if it takes snapshot of a DIV element, as there is a parent div element which covers all the items i want to take the snapshot of..

Please suggest me how can i go about doing this, i can use flash/javascript/php or any technology, thats not a constraint,

OS: Windows or MAC

P.S: I read many pages about taking the screenshot of the webpage, but in most of them, the answer is, since it violates security, its not allowed, but in my case there is no such security required, its a local page

Comment: i found a python program, webkit2png, which is taking the screenshots, now how can it be done to do the same at regular interval of the webpage, cos it always takes the first page which is the beginning of the animation

Comment: i have accepted an answer, but feel free to answer other methods you know, so that it might help people who want something different :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script using Selenium browse automation

- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/
- Pick your favorite language (Python, Java, Ruby, etc.) and Selenium library for it
- Write a Selenium script which opens the page and waits the amount of time you need
- Use Selenium screenshot API https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#70 to take a screenshot and save it to local disk
- Selenium API can be further used to query the dimensions of the element - where it appears, so you can post process the screenshot and crop it to relevant area only.

There exist client-side Javascript solutions to transform arbitary HTML DOM to `<canvas>`, but the output is not 100% accurate and works only for simple HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) will check out, one more clarification, can it also interact with the page controls?? the page is purely html5, so can it do actions like click a button??? :)

Comment: Selenium's name "Browser automation" is not only marketing speech :) You can even execute custom Javascript on loaded page if you wish.

Comment: thanks i'l check out, will accept this as the answer if it works out :)

Comment: thanks a lot, i was able to click it on my control and i was able to take screen shots after certain intervals,
one last thing, is it possible to know if a particular function in javascript is called, as i call a function Post() at the end of the animation, i want to know when it is called so that i can stop capturing the screenshots

Comment: You need to load custom Javascript for that. I do it in a way that my Javascript code sets a special global flag on window object at the end of the function. Selenium reads this flag on each run loop and if the flag is set takes a screenshot.

Comment: Also you can directly call Javascript functions from Selenium script and fiddle with the return value https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/bin/create_bg_thumbnails.py#L125